I don't know why the code isn't working properly
i'm doing PS and can't get the answer i want with the question.
Question:
String 'my_string' and 2 dimensional array 'queries' are given. Queries have its element [s,e] and it means reverse the my_string's index from s to e. Process the my_string as queries' order and return the solution.
Example:
my_string: "rermgorpsam"
queries: [[2, 3], [0, 7], [5, 9], [6, 10]]
result: "programmers"
the below is the answer i wrote and don't have any errors but keep getting the "rermgorpsam", not "programmers". i think there's no changes in my_string.
Englsih isn't my first language, so i'm not sure i explained properly, but it would be appreciated if you could let me know where is the problem.
import java.util.*;

class Solution {
    public String solution(String my_string, int[][] queries) {
        char[] charArr = my_string.toCharArray();

        for (int s = 0; s < queries.length; s++) {
            for (int e = 0; e < queries[s].length; e++) {
                reverse(charArr, queries[s][0], queries[s][1]);
            }
        }
        String answer = String.valueOf(charArr);
        return answer;
    }

    static void reverse(char[] arr, int s, int e) {

        char[] copy = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, s, e);

        for (int i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
            arr[s + i] = copy[copy.length - (i + 1)];
        }
    }
}

i think the problem is in the for loop or the method but don't know why...

Are you 100% sure you're modifying charArr? Have you tried using a debugger to see what your code actually does? Or just simple System.out.println() statements before and after calling reverse() to verify that it's changing the array as you expect it to do?

Did you try debugging the reverse function to see if the character array is being modified or not?

Your queries array is supposed to be an array of pairs, but you're iterating it as though it were an array of arbitrary-length arrays. I think that means you're performing each reversal twice.

The question has a poor title. Please edit so the question reflects specific issue. To better understand this site, I suggest the following resources, and their links: Tour, Help Center, [Write a Good Question[(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and Help Me Not a Question

If you want to become a developer, or otherwise regularly develop software, you will need to have debugging skills. If you are not familiar with using a debugger, using it on this code is a good place to start. Two resources: Debugger at StackOverflow, and How to Debug Small Programs.

If this problem has a web page, it would be polite, and likely helpful to include a link to that page. For one, the page might have additional examples, and better explanations. This might be the case if the problem comes from a programming practice / challenge site.

Here:
for (int s = 0; s < queries.length; s++) {
    for (int e = 0; e < queries[s].length; e++) {
        reverse(charArr, queries[s][0], queries[s][1]);
    }
}

You know that queries[s] has length 2, but you're iterating through it and calling reverse each time. That means you're calling reverse twice with the same arguments, presumably reversing characters back into the order they started in.
I suggest you get rid of the inner loop, leaving this:
for (int s = 0; s < queries.length; s++) {
    reverse(charArr, queries[s][0], queries[s][1]);
}

or more simply this:
for (int[] query : queries) {
    reverse(charArr, query[0], query[1]);
}

